# Remove white spaces between padding

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage at the moment that needs to be responsive for mobile devices. I have linked 2 images of how it looks right now, 1 for the normal design and 1 for how it looks on mobile right now. What I want to change, but don't know-how, is the colored padding. As you can see, there's a space between the icon above and the image under it, that white space I want to get rid of, either fill it with the same color or make the padding so that covers it up. Of course, I want the pc screen version to remain how it is on the image. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Mobile image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pWMc.jpg

Web image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH8ch.jpg

This is the code of the block that I am talking about, sorry for not including that earlier.

```html
<div class="col-md-4" 
        style=" width: 365px; background-color: #D7E1F8; padding-bottom: 141px; padding-left: 100px;">                
          <h1 class="icontextlb"> <br><br><br>
                
            <i class="icon-email iconstylelb"></i> 
            <br>
            2014
            
          </h1>
        </div>           

        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #D7E1F8; padding-bottom: 65px;">
          <br><br><br><img src="images/verhaal/kraan.png"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #D7E1F8; padding-bottom: 248.8px; padding-top: 20px;"> 
          <h1><br>
            Koppeling met web en de fabriek
          </h1>            
            <p>                  
              In 2014 was de koppeling met de website en de
              fabriek klaar. Dit betekend dat de orders
              automatisch verstuurd worden naar de fabriek. De
              orders worden hierdoor sneller doorgevoerd en de
              klant heeft eerder zijn glas op maat.
            </p>
        </div>
```

As you can see, I have 3 different paddings right here, for the image, icon, and text. It would be easier, I think, if it was just 1 bit of padding or a background color, instead of 3 separate parts that need adjusting.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Can you please add your html and css code? We cant debug images.

Comment: share some codes, but i think you should use flex-box to solve this problem

Comment: @user16** We would really like to help you. But without code and only two graphics, it doesn't make our job easy. And it's our time that we're sacrificing for this. so in return, you can also put in a little time so that we can help precisely. everything else is like guessing.

Comment: Have you removed all the default settings (e.g. margin/padding) that browsers use on elements if nothing else is set?

Comment: @AHaworth yes, just tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: @MaikLowrey I have edited my post with my code now, I apologize.

Comment: @user16935420 Thank you. Better already but your CSS is still missing ;-) It's best to only use the relevant parts, in case your style is too long.

Comment: you use bootstrap?

Comment: I do use Bootstrap, yes. I have a bit of CSS, but its just from something I tried out so not relevant here. The styling is in the style element in the HTML code. I know that might not be the best thing to do, but for now I use it.

Comment: Could you please make a working snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and also show any CSS you've tried like removing default settings - are you sure Bootstrap isn't putting some in?

Answer (score 0):

Padding actually is not the issue here. The issue with the white space is because you are using a fixed width on your first `col-md-4`. `Bootstrap` is already responsive in it self, so setting fixed widths will not help it out at all. The `col-md-4` already has a width associated width it `md-4`. I would suggest removing the fixed width and letting it revert back to its default of `width: 100%;` so it can use all of its column width.

**Side Note:** While the `br` element is great, `Bootstrap` columns are designed to break each div into sections, so the extra `br`'s and `padding`'s are a bit unnecessary, especially when using the Bootstrap framework. Lastly, I added a `container` and a `row` for good measures, it appears based on your **web image** you were already using a row.

```html
<head>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4" 
         style="background-color: #D7E1F8; padding-bottom: 141px; padding-left: 100px;">
         <h1 class="icontextlb"> <br><br><br>
            <i class="icon-email iconstylelb"></i> 
            <br>
            2014
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #D7E1F8; padding-bottom: 65px;">
         <br><br><br><img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #D7E1F8; padding-bottom: 248.8px; padding-top: 20px;">
         <h1><br>
            Koppeling met web en de fabriek
         </h1>
         <p>                  
            In 2014 was de koppeling met de website en de
            fabriek klaar. Dit betekend dat de orders
            automatisch verstuurd worden naar de fabriek. De
            orders worden hierdoor sneller doorgevoerd en de
            klant heeft eerder zijn glas op maat.
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```